# Run javascript code after template load and populate data from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m trying to create a web app, using Google Apps Script, in which when the the the certain condition are met, it will enable the `Select Element` with `id="posAppDesired"` then it will run the Google Apps Script to get the array of options, then return the array to the JavaScript and change the `innerHTML` of the Select Element. Then if the `button` with the `id="addPositionId"` is clicked, it will add a `template` and then it should load or duplicate the same `option`.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!-- POSITION APPLIED FOR--> 
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-9">
  <label for="posAppDesired">Select Desired Position</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="custom-select" id="posAppDesired" disabled>
      <option selecte disabled>Choose...</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="addPositionId"disabled>Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- FOR TEMPLATE --> 
  <div class="form-row" id="desiredPosition"></div>

<!-- MY TEMPLATE --> 
<template id="positionApplied">

<div class="form-group col-sm-9 posLine">
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="custom-select templatePositionClass" id="templatePosition" aria-label="Example select with button addon">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addPosButton" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary removePosButton" type="button">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</template>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var arrayOfPositions;
var currentlyAddedPositions = [];

document.getElementById("addPositionId").addEventListener("click", displayAddPosition);
document.getElementById("desiredPosition").addEventListener("click", afterDesiredPositionClicked);

function conditionOKAY(){ 
  var rollNum = document.getElementById("rnum").value;
  var appCat = document.getElementById("posCat").value;
  
 document.getElementById("posAppDesired").disabled = false;
 document.getElementById("addPositionId").disabled = false;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(positionCategoryCheck).getPositionCategory(IDNum, appCat);
}

function positionCategoryCheck(returnedPositions){
  arrayOfPositions = returnedPositions.filter(function(r){ return true; });

  var positionApplying = document.getElementById("posAppDesired");
  uniquePositions(positionApplying, arrayOfPositions, 0);
}

function uniquePositions(el, arrayOfPositions, index){
//  var currentlyAddedPositions = [];
  el.innerHTML = '<option selected disabled style="font-color: #B0B0B0;" value=""> Select Desired Station</option>';
  arrayOfPositions.forEach(function(r){
    if(currentlyAddedPositions.indexOf(r[index]) === -1){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = r[index];
    el.appendChild(option);
    currentlyAddedPositions.push(r[index]);
    }
  });  
}

//------FOR DESIRED POSITION/S----////
function displayAddPosition(arrayOfPositions){

  var addPosition = document.getElementById("desiredPosition");
  var positionTemplate = document.getElementById("positionApplied");
  var copyTemplate = positionTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
  addPosition.appendChild(copyTemplate);

    var testPost = document.querySelector(".templatePositionClass").closest(".posLine"); 


    var copiedPost = [];
    testPost.innerHTML = '<option selected disabled style="font-color: #B0B0B0;" value=""> Select Desired Station</option>';
    currentlyAddedPositions.forEach(function(r){
      if(copiedPost.indexOf(r) === -1){
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent = r;
      testPost.appendChild(option);
      copiedPost.push(r[0]);
      }
    });
}

function removePosition(){
  document.getElementById("desiredPosition")
}

function afterDesiredPositionClicked(e){

  if (e.target.matches(".addPosButton *, .addPosButton")){
    displayAddPosition();
  } else if (e.target.matches(".removePosButton *, .removePosButton")){
    e.target.closest(".posLine").remove();
  }
}
</script>
```

My Google Apps Script code:

```
function getPositionCategory(IDNum, appCat){
  if(appCat == "Main"){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urlPrequalData);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("VacantPositions");
  
  const posSelection = ws.getRange(1,1,1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var index = posSelection.indexOf(appCat)+1;
  var posValues = ws.getRange(2, index, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  return posValues;
}
```

The JavaScript code above was able to add the `template`, and then change the `innerHTML` of the `option` element  of that template. But if I click the `add button` again, the `option` element of the additional template does not change.

My aim is every time I clicked the "Add" button, it will load the template and right after the template loads, change the `option` in the Select Element of that template.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your showing script and `google-apps-script` in your tag?

Comment: @Tanaike The content of the option will be from Google Sheet. The google-apps-script will get the data from the google sheet, return the array in the java script and convert it to html as options.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "I have created a web app" (i.e. mention where are you hosting/ have deployed your web-app) and the relationship of it with Google Apps Script as the question body doesn't use Google Apps Script at all. Also clarify what you mean by  "somehow I was able to populate the Select Element options of the template" (the best is to show that "somehow")

Comment: @Rubén thank you for your edits and suggestions. I will also edit it again to make it clearer. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand `when the the right credentials are loaded it will, enable the html Select Element and then update its options from Google Sheets.`. Where is Google Apps Script used in your script?

Comment: @Tanaike My apologies. It is like a login page. Originally the Select Element was disabled and it will only be enabled if the the condition is met. Once it was enabled, it will run the Google Apps Script to get the array of options, then return the array to the Javascript and change the innerHTML of the Select Element. As suggested by Ruben, I will update my question to make it more clearer. Thank you and I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, I cannot understand `It is like a login page. Originally the Select Element was disabled and it will only be enabled if the the condition is met. Once it was enabled, it will run the Google Apps Script to get the array of options, then return the array to the Javascript and change the innerHTML of the Select Element.`, I would like to wait for `I will update my question to make it more clearer.`.

Comment: There is no need to include "EDITED" as the post has an automatic edit timestamp, it's bumped and a notification is sent to followers.

Comment: 1. prepare a backend function to get data from the sheet and return sheet values.     2. call app.script.run.function() when page loading.  using jquery or document event.  using withSucessHandler to pass the data return into a global variable, then other function can fetch the data.     then using events or triggers , when select or when clicked to populate the data you need.